# c#: strange shift in data buffer during communication with device

Tags: c#, serial-port, buffer

In my app I have to receive and process some data from device, connected through COM port. I do it partially. In that particular device first two bytes are the length of the packet (minus 2 since it doesn't take into account these very two bytes; so it is length of the rest of the packet after all). Then, since I know that device tends to send me its data slowly, I read rest of the packet in the loop, until all data has been read. But right here I encountered strange problem. Let's assume the entire packet (including these first two bytes with length) looks like this: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']. When I read first two bytes ('a' and 'b'), I'd expect rest of the packet to look like this: ['c', 'd', 'e']. But instead, it looks like this: ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']. How come second byte of the response is still in the read buffer? And why just the second one, without the previous one?

The code below shows how do I handle the communication process:

```
//The data array is some array with output data
//The size array is two-byte array to store frame-length bytes
//The results array is for device's response
//The part array is for part of the response that's currently in read buffer
port.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
//Receiving device's response (if there's any)
try
{
    port.Read(size, 0, 2); //Read first two bytes (packet's length) of the response
    //We'll store entire response in results array. We get its size from first two bytes of response
   //(+2 for these very bytes since they're not counted in the device's data frame)
    results = new byte[(size[0] | ((int)size[1] << 8)) + 2];
    results[0] = size[0]; results[1] = size[1]; //We'll need packet size for checksum count
    //Time to read rest of the response
    for(offset = 2; offset < results.Length && port.BytesToRead > 0; offset += part.Length)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5); //Device's quite slow, isn't it
        try
        {
            part = new byte[port.BytesToRead];
            port.Read(part, 0, part.Length); //Here's where old data is being read
        }
        catch(System.TimeoutException)
        {
                //Handle it somehow
        }
        Buffer.BlockCopy(part, 0, results, offset, part.Length);
    }
    if(offset < results.Length) //Something went wrong during receiving response
        throw new Exception();
}
catch(Exception)
{
    //Handle it somehow
}
```

Comment: Oh, and when I read the second time (when I get that old byte, that is), port.BytesToRead also implies there's one more byte. I mean, if packet has x bytes in total and I read first two bytes, port.BytesToRead == x - 1 instead x - 2.

Comment: If it is that slow, then do a "port.DiscardInBuffer()" after reading the first two bytes.

Comment: It actually makes everything worse.

Comment: Ouch! maybe try something like this: http://codesamplez.com/programming/serial-port-communication-c-sharp

Comment: You cannot ignore the return value of Read().  It is 1, not 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a traditional mistake, you cannot ignore the return value of Read().  It tells you how many bytes were *actually* received.  It will be at least 1, not more than *count*.  However many are present in the receive buffer, BytesToRead tells you.  Simply keep calling Read() until your happy:

```
int cnt = 0;
while (cnt < 2) cnt += port.Read(size, cnt, 2 - cnt);
```

Just use the same code in the 2nd part of your code so you don't burn 100% core without the Sleep() call.  Do keep in mind that TimeoutException is just as likely when you read the size, more likely actually.  It is a fatal exception if it is thrown when cnt > 0, you can't resynchronize anymore.

Comment: You're right. Thanks a lot, it's much better sollution than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, strange enough, but when I read first two bytes separatedly:

```
port.Read(size, 0, 1); //Read first two bytes (packet's length) of the response
port.Read(size, 1, 1); //Second time, lol
```

Everything works just fine, no matter what kind of data pack do I receive from device.

Answer (score 0):

The documntation for SerialPort contains the following text:

> Because the SerialPort class buffers data, and the stream contained in
>   the BaseStream property does not, the two might conflict about how
>   many bytes are available to read. The BytesToRead property can
>   indicate that there are bytes to read, but these bytes might not be
>   accessible to the stream contained in the BaseStream property because
>   they have been buffered to the SerialPort class.

Could this explain why `BytesToRead` is giving you confusing values?

Personally, I always use the `DataReceived` event and in my event handler, I use `ReadExisting()` to read all immediately available data and add it to my own buffer. I don't attempt to impose any meaning on the data stream at that level, I just buffer it; instead I'll typically write a little state machine that takes characters out of the buffer one at a time and parses the data into whatever format is required.

Alternatively, you could use the [ReactiveExtensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) to produce an observable sequence of received characters and then layer observers on top of that. I do it with a couple of extension methods like this:

```
public static class SerialObservableExtensions
    {
    static readonly Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    /// <summary>
    ///     Captures the <see cref="System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.DataReceived" /> event of a serial port and returns an
    ///     observable sequence of the events.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="port">The serial port that will act as the event source.</param>
    /// <returns><see cref="IObservable{Char}" /> - an observable sequence of events.</returns>
    public static IObservable<EventPattern<SerialDataReceivedEventArgs>> ObservableDataReceivedEvents(
        this ISerialPort port)
        {
        var portEvents = Observable.FromEventPattern<SerialDataReceivedEventHandler, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs>(
            handler =>
                {
                log.Debug("Event: SerialDataReceived");
                return handler.Invoke;
                },
            handler =>
                {
                // We must discard stale data when subscribing or it will pollute the first element of the sequence.
                port.DiscardInBuffer();
                port.DataReceived += handler;
                log.Debug("Listening to DataReceived event");
                },
            handler =>
                {
                port.DataReceived -= handler;
                log.Debug("Stopped listening to DataReceived event");
                });
        return portEvents;
        }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets an observable sequence of all the characters received by a serial port.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="port">The port that is to be the data source.</param>
    /// <returns><see cref="IObservable{char}" /> - an observable sequence of characters.</returns>
    public static IObservable<char> ReceivedCharacters(this ISerialPort port)
        {
        var observableEvents = port.ObservableDataReceivedEvents();
        var observableCharacterSequence = from args in observableEvents
                                          where args.EventArgs.EventType == SerialData.Chars
                                          from character in port.ReadExisting()
                                          select character;
        return observableCharacterSequence;
        }
}
```

The `ISerialPort` interface is just a header interface that I extracted from the `SerialPort` class, which makes it easier for me to mock it when I'm unit testing.